# Captcha form submit without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code in the page where's captcha needed:

```
<?php


/** Validate captcha */
if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {

    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) !== $_SESSION['captcha']) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'fail();'
   , '</script>';
    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) == $_SESSION['captcha']) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'success();'
   , '</script>';
    }

    $request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);


    unset($_SESSION['captcha']);


}
if (empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
 echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
   , 'fail();'
   , '</script>';
    }

?>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form>
<img src="../captcha.php"/>

<input type="text" name="captcha" /></div>

<input name="submit">
</form>
```

What's about captcha.php I don't think it's needed, but if so, just let me know.

I need it to submit the captcha without refreshing page.

I've tried this without any success:

```
      $(function () {
        $('form').bind('click', function (event) {

event.preventDefault();// using this page stop being refreshing 

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$('form').bind('click', function (event) {` to `$('form').bind('submit', function (event) {`

It makes little sense to bind to the click event on the form. You either want to bind the click event on the submit button, or the submit event on the form. I recommend the latter, it covers more cases.

Comment: this helps, but how to check everything like is in php?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Can you elaborate on the part you need help with?

Comment: 3 parts like `  if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) !== $_SESSION['captcha'])` witch checks if the code was entered right, if not and one is just function on submit (I didn't find another working way to check if the field is empty)